# Two column webpage, DIV overflows

Tags: html, css

I need some help, this is bothering me...

I have the following DIV structure:

```
<div id="principal">
    <div id="colIzquierda">Some Content</div>
    <div id="colDerecha">Some Content</div>
</div>
```

And the following CSS code to style it:

```
body, html {
    height:100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px; }

#principal {
    width:1000px;
    height:100%;
    margin:0px auto; }

#colIzquierda {
    width:250px;
    float:left; }

#colDerecha {
    width:750px;
    float:right; }
```

I have a problem when I fill for example #colDerecha with lots of content, and it overflows the height of the windows of my browser, then I can see something like this:

[image: Caption]

Where the dark grey = #principal, light grey = body, green = #colDerecha.

How can I make #principal gain the same height as #colDerecha always, when #colDerecha content is bigger than the screen size?

I don´t know if I explain myself enough...

Please some ideas? I have tried adding height:100% to both #colIzquierda and #colDerecha, but does not do what I want. It overflows the same, but in other way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common approach would be to change the `display` of the parent element, `#principal`, to `table`, then set the `display` of the children elements to `table-cell`. In doing so, `#colIzquierda` and `#colDerecha` will fill the remaining space.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/NzE7g/)

```
#principal {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:gray;
    display:table;
}
#colIzquierda {
    width:25%;
    display:table-cell;
}
#colDerecha {
    width:75%;
    display:table-cell;
    background:gold;
}
```

Comment: Ok, this works flawlessly and does exactly what I need! Thank you, is there any kind of browser compatibility issue with this code? I think <IE8 may not work?

Comment: @qalbiol Support can be seen [here](http://caniuse.com/css-table). It will work in IE8 and up.

Comment: @downvoter Care to explain what is wrong with my answer? How can I improve it..? It solves the OP's problem. For what it's worth, these are CSS tables, not HTML tables. It's not hackish.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="principal">
    <div id="colIzquierda">Some Content</div>
    <div id="colDerecha">Some Content</div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

Why use the PHP tag in your question ?

Comment: Thanks Vincent, but I cannot make it work with your solution, I already have a footer div with the clear:both; property... I added php by inertia, sry :)

Comment: Did you try my code ? As mentionned by Tim B, you have to use clear property. This should works.